# Swapping tubeless tyres as a practice

Tags: tire, tubeless, gravel

Have a Grizl with the DT Swiss G1800 wheels. Want to run burlier tyres like the Continental's Race Kings (2.0) and have the original G-Bites (45mm) in reserve for some bikepacking. Both to be run tubeless.
Can the tubeless tyre switching (swapping a TL tyre with the intent of someday putting it on again) be considered a detrimental practice? Will the tyre the second or third time it is mounted on a wheel be less performant or could one expect problems mounting it?

Comment: I just had a nightmare experience with trying to remove Contis GP5000S TL from Giant Carbon rims (road bike). Using good quality plastic levers from Topeak not only have I failed at removing the tyre, but managed to damage the rim in the process. Take away: be very very careful with carbon, I believe that aluminium can take much more punishment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no practical experience with your question. While I’d defer to someone who does, here’s my reasoning. In theory, it is *possible* that repeated installations might cause wear, especially to the softer of the materials involved. For example, square taper cranks or BB spindles may wear, especially if installed loosely. However, with good materials and barring installation error, we know that you often have to remove and reinstall square taper cranks many, many times to cause wear.

Keep in mind that it's generally expected that many people may replace a tube once or more during a tire's life. If the beads experienced wear from a couple of installations, I would expect manufacturers to have received complaints and to have addressed that issue by now. I have no idea how many times would cause the beads to stretch or to wear, but I expect that if bead wear exists, it would only show after many installations - a few dozen, at least.

I don’t expect aluminum or carbon rims to wear at all from repeated tire installations. Again, I would defer to someone with actual practical experience or lab test results, but it seems extremely unlikely that the rims would wear.

Comment: Overall I agree, and running (even puncture-resistant) tubed tyres I'd say you're talking more like 10 tube changes during the life of a tyre, plus anything from swapping for changing riding conditions.  I have however had one winter tyre that wouldn't seat properly in its 2nd winter.  I got it on once, but after that it always blew off the rim, even at pressures too low to register.  I suspect it was marginal to start with, and swapping it on and off was the last straw